# Java fixed number of elements in an array

Tags: java

When I create an array in Java - int array[] and array=new int[some number] -

How can I construct it if I don't know how many values it will hold so that I have enough space in it?

Comment: In that situation don't use an array but rather an ArrayList.

Comment: Actually: In case of doubt never use an array at all, but default on ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For growing arrays, use `ArrayList`.

If the array should contain primitive types, you can wrap them:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

array.add(new Integer(4));
array.add(new Integer(-5));
array.add(new Integer(4));
array.add(new Integer(2));
```

However, when the values change a lot, you keep instantiating and throwing away Integer  instances, because it is immutable. It's not very high performance either.

My solution: create a wrapper yourself, with a public value field.

This is my wrapper, which is also suitable for `TreeMap` and the likes, which sort items by their natural order.

```
public class MyInteger implements Comparable<MyInteger>
{
    public int  value;

    public MyInteger(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyInteger o)
    {
        return value - o.value;
    }
}
```

Now you can do stuff like:

```
array.get(2).value++;
```

Answer (score 10):

In that case you might wanna use `ArrayList` or some other dynamic collection.
You do not have to mention the size of ArrayList and you can add as many element as you want at run time. the size grows dynamically.

Declaration

```
List arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

if using JDK 1.5 or greater then you can also mention type of elements that this list will hold.

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/array_list_demo.shtml

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is the simplest answer, however if you want a more memory efficient approach you can use TIntArrayList (which wraps a `int[]`)

Comment: I don't have TIntArrayList in my Java 1.6 JDK

Comment: You can search for it, if an additional library is ok for you. ;)